# How can I translate this class code to hooks? - reactnative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to translate this class React Component to React Hooks. I have tested the code and it works, but now I want to do it using hooks, the problem is that I dont fully understands how to do that, I tried to do it but it doesn't work at all, I thought that in every `this.variablename` should be changed for a `setvariablename` but I can't make it work.

Can I have some help? Thanks a lot guys.

im using this library react-native-image-crop-picker

```
    export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fileList:[]
    }
  }

onSelectedImage = (image) => {
  let newDataImg = this.state.fileList;
  const source = {uri: image.path};
  let item = {
    id: Date.now(),
    url: source,
    content: image.data
  };
  newDataImg.push(item);
  this.setState({fileList: newDataImg})
};

  takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    }).then(image => {
      this.onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  };
  choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true
    }).then(image => {
      this.onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  };

renderItem = ({item, index}) =>{
  return(
    <View>
      <Image source={item.url} style={styles.itemImage} />
    </View>
  )
};

render() {
  let {fileList}= this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={fileList}
          keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString() }
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          extraData={this.state}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.viewData} onPress={this.takePhotoFromCamera}>
          <text>Foto</text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.viewData} onPress={this.choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
          <text>galeria</text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
};
}
```

Comment: Um, are you quite sure this is working properly? It's full of syntax errors

Comment: well its an example i took from a video, an implemented on other things i had, i only need help with the part i took from his video, so i went and wrote the code here, so once i have the translate to hooks i can implement other tings on the view

Comment: Well can you fix the errors you have here? If you were to copy this into VS Code for example and select JSX, the first error (after the parenthesis in the wrong direction for your `constructor`) is `this.setState( state: {filenewDataImg})`. That's syntactically invalid, and `filenewDataImg` isn't a valid reference either.

Comment: you were right i had some errors, i have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement on devcass' answer, using `useCallback()` to properly memoize callbacks, and avoiding passing object literals to children components (e.g. `extraData={{ fileList }}`), and making immutable updates to the state variable with the callback signature of `setState()`:

```
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function App(props) {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const state = useMemo(() => ({ fileList }), [fileList]);

  const onSelectedImage = useCallback((image) => {
    setFileList(fileList => {
      const newDataImg = [...fileList];
      const source = { uri: image.path };
      const item = {
        id: Date.now(),
        url: source,
        content: image.data
      };
      newDataImg.push(item);
      return newDataImg;
    });
  }, [setFileList]);

  const takePhotoFromCamera = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const choosePhotoFromLibrary = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={item.url} style={styles.itemImage} />
      </View>
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={fileList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        extraData={state}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
        <text>Foto</text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
        <text>galeria</text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: while i was able to make it run, for one reason when you select the image it doesnt show on the screen maybe something went wrong in the translation?

Comment: @user10625391 this code, and devcass' code both behave identically to the code you've provided in the question. My suggestion would be to copy the code in your question back into your project, troubleshoot that and fix it, then copy that resulting code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
export default function App(props) {

const [fileList, setFileList] = React.useState([]);

const onSelectedImage = (image) => {
 let newDataImg fileList;
 const source = {uri: image.path};
 let item = {
   id: Date.now(),
   url: source,
   content: image.data
 };
 newDataImg.push(item);
 setFileList(newDataImg)
};

const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
   ImagePicker.openCamera({
     width: 300,
     height: 400,
     cropping: true,
   }).then(image => {
     onSelectedImage(image);
     console.log(image);
   });
 };
 const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
   ImagePicker.openPicker({
     width: 300,
     height: 400,
     cropping: true
   }).then(image => {
     onSelectedImage(image);
     console.log(image);
   });
 };

const renderItem = ({item, index}) =>{
 return(
   <View>
     <Image source={item.url} style={styles.itemImage} />
   </View>
 )
};

 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
         data={fileList}
         keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString() }
         renderItem={renderItem}
         extraData={{ fileList }}
       />

       <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.viewData} onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
         <text>Foto</text>
       </TouchableOpacity>

       <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.viewData} onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
         <text>galeria</text>
       </TouchableOpacity>

   </View>
 );
};
```

Comment: while i was able to make it run, for one reason when you select the image it doesnt show on the screen, maybe something went wrong in the translation?